# using rescue in variable assignment

Tags: ruby, rescue

I have this

```
User.new ( gender: auth.extra.raw_info.gender.capitalize, ...)
```

auth is a hash that looks like this

```
auth => {:extra => { :raw_info => { :gender => ... , .. }, ..} ..}
```

sometimes, for whatever reason, the gender doesn't exist and I want to have a default value for it when I create a new user

If I try

`gender: auth.extra.raw_info.gender.try(:capitalize) || "Male"`

but the gender itself doesn't exist, and I can't `try` on gender

using   `gender: auth.extra.raw_info.gender.capitalize rescue "Male"`

also doesn't work since it says I can't use capitalize on nil (which is gender)

Is there a way to do this without using a variable for this (since it will become messier)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the standard way to do this is to use [reverse_merge](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/Hash/reverse_merge):

```
auth.reverse_merge! {:extra => { :raw_info => { :gender => "Male" } } }
```

Comment: so thats adding the gender to the hash only if it doesn't exist?

Comment: Exactly. "Performs the opposite of merge, with the keys and values from the first hash taking precedence over the second."